# How do you statically link SDL2 to your project in CodeBlocks 13.12 on Raspbian Jessie Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, codeblocks, raspbian, sdl-2

I am trying to get my SDL2 program statically linking to ask so it is a standalone application. I have been searching all day long but I can't get it to work. Here is my other linker options in CodeBlocks "-lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer  -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_net". I tried -static but it just introduced a giant pile of libgcc errors. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `-Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_net -Wl,-Bdynamic`, if you have statc versions for all of this libraries.

Comment: Hello keltar, unfortunately I am now getting a whole pile of SDL_InitDynamicAPI and other SDL errors.

Comment: What errors exactly?

Comment: Errors like SDL_Init_Dynamic_Api undefined references. Maybe there is a version of this http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/static-link-sdl-having-issues-813937/ for SDL2?

Comment: Okay, your call, if you decline to post exact error message - I have no means to help you. Good luck. You probably need to add more libraries to link chain because static libs have no dependency information.

Comment: I solved that part. I needed to link use sdl2-config --static-libs in the terminal and put the returned information into the other linker options section of CodeBlocks. Then I statically linked to -lpthreads and removed any dynamic linking to it. When I get what I passed in there in a form that I can paste it into here I will. I know I can't be the only one who has ever needed to statically link to SDL2 ;). Thanks for your kelp keltar! :)

Comment: Note that SDL2 have dynamic loading API and user can override your static library with provided dynamic one - https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RyanGordon/posts/TB8UfnDYu4U

Comment: Sounds good. As long as the end user doesn't have to install SDL2 on their system in order to run the application I am fine :)

Comment: If that was the reason, you could've just distributed shared libraries with your binary, with some rpath or LD_LIBRARY_PATH tricks.

Comment: keltar that sounds great, how would I do that?

Comment: shell script that does `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD; ./your_program` is quite common practice (e.g. steam, maya and countless others). Rpath is e.g. `gcc -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' your_object_files.o -o your_program -llibraries` at linking stage.

Comment: Sounds interesting. How would I accomplish this CodeBlocks 13.12?

Comment: Sorry I don't use codeblocks (or any other IDE for that matter). Should be something like 'linker flags'. Shell script variant requires no changes.

Comment: That's alright :) I am going with linking .so files instead. Thanks for your help! :D